# Merging array for parent category in Cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I want to be able to group SpecificationCategory.name as parent category and Specifications under as children so that SpecificationCategory.name does not get repeated in the array.

Is there a way to do this in Cake?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Specification] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 15
                    [name] => AMD Phenom
                    [specification_category_id] => 1
                    [subsubcategory_id] => 1
                    [created] => 2012-10-16 08:18:27
                    [modified] => 2012-10-16 08:18:27
                )

            [SpecificationCategory] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => Processor Type
                    [created] => 2012-10-15 13:50:03
                    [modified] => 2012-10-15 13:50:03
                )

            [Subsubcategory] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => Laptops
                    [subcategory_id] => 1
                    [created] => 2012-06-24 02:23:40
                    [modified] => 2012-06-24 02:23:40
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Specification] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 12
                    [name] => AMD E350
                    [specification_category_id] => 1
                    [subsubcategory_id] => 1
                    [created] => 2012-10-16 08:18:02
                    [modified] => 2012-10-16 08:18:02
                )

            [SpecificationCategory] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => Processor Type
                    [created] => 2012-10-15 13:50:03
                    [modified] => 2012-10-15 13:50:03
                )

            [Subsubcategory] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => Laptops
                    [subcategory_id] => 1
                    [created] => 2012-06-24 02:23:40
                    [modified] => 2012-06-24 02:23:40
                )

        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your just trying to get a listing by SpecificationCategory I would just do the find from that model and the array would list all Specifications under each category. This assumes Specifications hasMany SpecificationCategory.